# why do I get this oblong shape brush icon in sculpt mode

Tags: sculpting

All the brushes have this oblong shaped profile(blue) when I select the radius via "F" keyword even though the face is parallel to the XZ plane. Is there a setting that I have accidentally changed?

[image]

Comment: go to object mode, press ctrl+A and apply scale, your brush should be normal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to explain why this happened in the first place... this is the default cube with a normal brush:
[image]

And when you scale your object in only 1 axis, for example, axis Z, this happens:
[image]

This is simply due to the reason that you scaled it... it even gives you this warning message:
[image]

It simply warns you that you scaled your object not in all axis but only in 1 or 2. Solution is to apply scale by pressing Ctrl+A and selecting Scale, this will set your object to 1/1/1 and your object will be uniform once again

Comment: the warning message is very subtle as I hardly ever notice it! I have to pay more attention to it. Im assuming it cannot be moved to a more line of sign view?